# Pass data as parameters to Logic apps from MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-logic-apps

i have tried calling logic apps from a MVC application.Following is the method i'm using in a "create" action method (in a mvc controller) to pass data as parameters to Logic app url.

[image]
In the above method , i can use "await" only within async method.So i have changed the method to async as shown below

```
public async Task<JsonResult> Add_recordAsync(register rs)
{
}
```

issue is how can i resolve following error.i'm new to dotnet programming. Appreciate your help.
[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.serialize?view=netcore-3.1#System_Text_Json_JsonSerializer_Serialize__1___0_System_Text_Json_JsonSerializerOptions_

Answer (score 2):

Now i'm able to call / trigger logic app url from MVC application. Following is my code.It works absolutely fine.
[image]

[image]

Following is the link for reference. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-send-email?tabs=dotnet#more-resources

Comment: StringContent() has 2 more overloads, second overload can accept 3 parameters: content, Encoding and mediatype so this can be simplified to:

StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are developing the code with .NET Framework. When we develop with .NET Core, it will prompt to install and using the package `System.Text.Json` when we write the code:

```
var jsonData = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new { email = "a-valid@emailaddress.com", due = "4/1/2020", task = "My new task!" });
```

But when we develop with .NET Framework, it will just suggest us `using Newtonsoft.Json`. So we need to install it by ourself, just click "Tools" --> "NuGet Package Manager" --> "Manage Nuget Packages for Solution..." in your visual studio.

[image]

Then search for "System.Text.Json" and install it.
[image]

After that, you can use this namespace in your code.

Hope it helps~

Comment: Thanks a lot Shen. Do you have any idea on this --> In the above method , i can use "await" only within async method.So i have changed the method to async as shown below-->

public async Task<JsonResult> Add_recordAsync(register rs)
{
}    but i dont want to change it to async method.plese help